# Use function inside another function in C

Tags: c

I have `function a` that retuns an integer, and `function b` that also returns an integer. How can I use functions `a` and `b` inside another function? Example:

```
int a(int number){
    return number-5;
}

int b(int number){
    return number+5;
}

double GetPercentage(int n1, int n2){

    return (n1/n2)*100;
}

int main(){

    GetPercentage(a(10),b(10));

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: `33.33`.

Comment: Why do you expect any output at all?

Comment: Your problem is that n1/n2 is an integer. Try (float)n1/n2
http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, you need to print the return value from `GetPercentage`. As is, you're not doing anything with it, so the program doesn't have any output.

```
double p = GetPercentage(a(10),b(10));
printf("%f\n", p);
```

Two, you need to force the division to be done with floating point. Otherwise when you divide two `int`s the result will be truncated to an integer: 5/15 = 0.3333, which is truncated to 0, and 0*100 is 0 instead of 33.33.

```
return (((double) n1) / n2) * 100;
```

Comment: Solves it. Got the idea - thanks for your time :) Will accept the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that integer division is occurring with `n1` and `n2`, and thus 5/15 -> 0..  Your problem isn't composition of functions.

So change `return (n1/n2) * 100;` to `return (100.0 * (double)n1 / (double) n2 );`
Yes the extra casts are verbose; but it will make it clearer to someone such as yourself who is reading the code that you are trying to carry out floating point division

That aside there won't be any printed output unless you add a print statement of some sort.
perhaps use printf like so:

```
double p = GetPercentage( a( 10 ), b( 10 ) );
printf( "%f\n", p );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are losing some data due to integer division in the line

```
 return (n1/n2)*100;
```

Instead, use

```
 return (100.0*n1/n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, but you are not doing anything with the return value of `GetPercentage`. You may add the following changes:

```
double result = GetPercentage(a(10),b(10));
printf("%f\n", result);
```

And at the top of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Also make sure to return a value of type `double`. Therefore, change your `GetPercentage` function to the following:

```
return (100 * n1/n2);
```

Comment: n1/n2 is still an int